# login into website using the username and password in php curl

Tags: php, html, curl

I'm facing with error which is not resolved from 3 days . let me know where i'm going wrong . Like wise i need to login into portal and redirect it to next webpage .

```
   url="http://gis.lntecc.com/BWSSBLnT/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fbwssblnt%2fScada.aspx%3ffield1%3dKathriguppe%2cSW2DM0402%2c235505H073%2c450&field1=Kathriguppe,SW2DM0402,235505H073,450";

  $useragent="xyz";


    $ch = curl_init();


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);


   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'abc:123');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);



  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Login1_Username=abc&Login1_Password=123');


  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


  $store = curl_exec ($ch);
 echo $store;

  curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Is the website expecting a post method  for username and password?

Answer (score 1):

The post field names on the website are not the same in your code.

> [image]

The proper names are `Login1$UserName` and `Login1$Password`, you need to look at the name attribute, not the ID.

That being the case, your code should be:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'Login1$UserName=abc&Login1$Password=123');
```

Answer (score 0):

hey guys easy way to login into the webpages using php script is just removing url and following with the thing 
             header("Location: http://gis.lntecc.com/bwssblnt/Scada.aspx?                  field1=Kathriguppe%2cSW2DM0402%2c235505H073%2c450")